# How many copies of Jackbox Party Pack 3 are needed for two households?

Tags: jackbox-party-pack

My sister and her husband are across the state; myself, my wife, daughter, and sister's son are at my house -- how many copies of Jackbox Party Pack would I need for all of us to play?  2 or 6?

Comment: So just to get it straight, is this the arrangement of people? [House 1: Sister and her Husband] [House 2: You, your wife, your daughter, and your sister's son]. Is that correct?

Comment: @Echoleta:  Correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Jackbox games only require one copy of the game. All other players play using the jackbox.tv website.

Everyone will need to see the screen though, so you'll need to find a solution for that. I believe you can use Steam Remote Play

Comment: I've used Google Hangout to success as well.  Something with low delay